# Alamofire gives one extra item

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

In server app, I have 12 users. But if I build soft, I have 12 ids, but 13 firstnames, 13 lastnames, and, of course, 13 full names. But if I logout (it means delete whole data) and login again, everything is fine and Alamofire gives me 12 items of everything. API is fine, it is something in my code.

Examples of arrays:
ids
[5, 12, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 22, 25, 28, 29, 30]

lastnames
[, doe, wick, smith, etc.]

So ids are good, but lastnames have on their beginning one spare item (comma before doe means one spare item). So why is there one extra item with blank string?

```
var firstnamesOfUsers: [String]!
var lastnamesOfUsers: [String]!
var idsOfUsers: [Int]!
var namesOfUsers: [String]!

func getUsers(){
        Alamofire.request(.GET, "https://\(domainText).projektove.cz/users.json", parameters: ["limit": 1000])
            .responseJSON { (request, response, JSONresponse, error) in
                if( error == nil){
                    var responseJSON = JSONresponse as NSMutableDictionary
                    let json = JSON(responseJSON)
                    var users = json["users"]
//                    println(users)

                    if users.count > 0 {
                        for index in 0...users.count-1 {
                            firstnamesOfUsers.append(users[index]["firstname"].stringValue)
                            lastnamesOfUsers.append(users[index]["lastname"].stringValue)
                            idsOfUsers.append(users[index]["id"].intValue)
                            namesOfUsers.append(users[index]["firstname"].stringValue + " " + users[index]["lastname"].stringValue)
                        }
                    }

                }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Immediately after populating the arrays only 1 of them is correct? Or some other code in the app later changes the arrays?

Comment: Why are you splitting up individual fields into separate arrays? Why not create a `User` model object and manage an array of users instead?

Comment: @Wain No, every item is correct except the first. It's empty item (string with no character). When I logout, I set every item to empty field. For example:

firstnamesOfUsers = []

And then, if I login again, everything is fine and the field are ok.

Comment: @mattt I know it is not a best practice, but I don't understand a concept about modeling objects.

Answer (score 0):

You code sample has several issues, the most important being your lack of a model object structure which @mattt has already pointed out. You certainly have the opportunity to improve here. Below is the same logic, just redesigned to be a bit more robust.

**User**

```
struct User {
    let id: Int
    let firstName: String
    let lastName: String
    var fullName: String { return "\(self.firstName) \(self.lastName)" }
}
```

**UserService**

```
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

class UserService {
    typealias GetUsersSuccessHandler = [User] -> Void
    typealias GetUsersFailureHandler = (NSURLRequest?, NSHTTPURLResponse?, NSError?) -> Void

    class func getUsers(#success: GetUsersSuccessHandler?, failure: GetUsersFailureHandler?) -> Request? {
        let domainText = "some_random_url"

        let request = Alamofire.request(.GET, "https://\(domainText).projektove.cz/users.json", parameters: ["limit": 1000])
        request.validate()
        request.responseJSON { request, response, jsonObject, error in
            if error != nil || jsonObject == nil {
                failure?(request, response, error)
                return
            }

            let json = JSON(jsonObject!)
            let jsonUsers = json["users"]

            var users = [User]()

            for jsonUser in jsonUsers.arrayValue {
                let id = jsonUser["id"].int
                let firstName = jsonUser["firstname"].string
                let lastName = jsonUser["lastname"].string

                if firstName != nil && lastName != nil && id != nil {
                    let user = User(id: id!, firstName: firstName!, lastName: lastName!)
                }
            }

            success?(users)
        }

        return request
    }
}
```

**SomeClass**

```
class SomeClass {
    func fetchUsers() {
        UserService.getUsers(
            success: { users in
                println("Fetched users: \(users)")
            },
            failure: { request, response, error in
                println("Failed to fetch users: \(error)")
            }
        )
    }
}
```

This code sample compiles so feel free to give it a whirl. Please pay particular attention to the use of the `User` model object and how it gets created in the `responseJSON` completion handler.

Hopefully this helps get you going in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you, but how can I call this code? I don't understand this async stuff.

Comment: Apologies, I updated the answer with `SomeClass` showing how you can easily call the `UsersService`. As for the async stuff, reading [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html) article from the Swift programming guide will help along with [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/ConcurrencyandApplicationDesign/ConcurrencyandApplicationDesign.html).

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try it as soon as possible.